# Changing HTML video stream source/quality on the fly

Tags: javascript, video-streaming, jss

**Background:**
I'm working on a video project with 50+ short videos (10min, 720p) that I want to present online. My current architecture is to placing 16 video tags in a 4x4 grid, and then randomly setting their source on load using JavaScript, and on click zooming a video to cover the full screen until clicked again.

**The problem:**
Each video in 720p webm is around 80mb. With 16 videos that is 1.3GB totally, or 130MB per minute, or 2MB per second. Which is a ridiculous amount of data, I think, maybe I'm wrong. The each video is so big (80mb) is to support the zoom-full-screen feature.

**My idea for a solution:**
Each video in two resolutions, and use the low resolution for the grid layout, and the higher resolution on the click-to-zoom.

**My question:** How to make this smooth? Can I preload the high resolution video on click in the background at the position of the low resolution video? And make the shift in the CSS transform? Or is there a better way to do this?

**Secondary question:** How to host this online? Can I put the videos on vimeo maybe? Right now I'm using wordpress.com hosting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The normal way to achieve something like that is to encode the video using an adaptive bitrate format. The two primary formats for that would either be HLS or MPEG-DASH. Most online encoding platforms can provide those as outputs. Normally you would encode 5-6 different qualities (this helps with users that are on wifi, where bandwidth might constantly be changing) but you could easily encode it in just two different qualities.

Normally the players would be able to select the right quality automatically, but you can manage that yourself if you want.

If you are going to use HLS, you can use [hls.js](https://github.com/video-dev/hls.js) and its [Quality Switch API](https://github.com/video-dev/hls.js/blob/master/docs/API.md#quality-switch-control-api). For MPEG-DASH, a good player to use would be [Shaka Player](https://shaka-player-demo.appspot.com/docs/api/tutorial-basic-usage.html) and then set it like this:

```
player.configure({enableAdaption: false});
player.selectVideoTrack(trackId);
```

If you want to switch specifically on fullscreen, just listen for the fullscreen events on the players.

Comment: Thank you for a great reply. My web host (surftown) doesn't provide Node.js so I guess hls.js is my best for me. A follow question, is it possible to set a buffering strategy that makes hls.js aware that I have 16 low res videos that needs to be maintained. My web host allows for 5 concurrent requests, so I would need them to be cycled through all the videos.

Comment: @AndreasBurmester Neither of those players would require Node.js on the serverside. They are all clientside. Also, they are not actually holding open the connections, but instead fetching small segmented video files, so concurrent request limits shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Right I got confused, it's the build and test environment for Shaka that is dependency heavy.

Prerequisites
You can build Shaka on Linux, Windows, or Mac. To get the sources and compile the library, you will need:

Git v1.9+ https://git-scm.com/downloads
Python v2.7 https://www.python.org/downloads/
Java Runtime Environment v8+ https://java.com/en/download/
NodeJS v6+ https://nodejs.org/en/download/
A local web server, such as Apache https://httpd.apache.org/
NOTE: A local web server is required because browsers place restrictions on applications from file:/// URLs.

Comment: Do you any recommendation for tools to encode the different bitrates/resolutions? Now I used Handbreak on Ubuntu and changed the resolution for each file(720p, 360p, 180p). However when I try using Bento4 to generate dash from it, then only some works, and others don't because... `ERROR: video tracks are not aligned ("File 2#1" differs from File 1#1)` I guess that Handbreak didn't make the files similar enough?

Comment: Never mind. I found that Bento4 comes with its own encoder that solves the problem. For people that might come after me, it's important that the key frames are aligned. Handbreak tries to be smart selecting key frames but that doesn't work with dash format.